# How to export html table to excel or pdf in a HTML page through jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I have a html page with a table which is populated dynamically. I need to put 2 buttons below it which enables exporting the table structure data to Excel and PDF.

What is the best/easiest approach to implement this?

I will prefer some Javascript/jQuery solution. I have seen [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/documentation#jquery_example), but I think its a paid service. I need something similar which works on IE8 browser. Please Help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/#) is a plug-in for the DataTables HTML table enhancer, which adds a highly customisable button toolbar to a DataTable. Key features include:

- Copy to clipboard
- Save table data as CSV, XLS or PDF files
- Print view for clean printing
- Row selection options
- Easy use predefined buttons
- Simple customisation of buttons
- Well defined API for advanced control

Comment: Doesn't display the HTML output, for example BOLD or UNDERLINE or UNORDERED LIST within the table cell.

Answer (score 4):

```
 $("button").click(function () {
  var str="";
  $('tr').each(function() {

        $(this).find('td').each(function() {

         str=str+$(this).html()+"\t";
  });
      str=str+"\n";

  });

  alert(str);

        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(str));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Vr89/1/

Comment: I adapted it slightly so that it has column headers as well:
`var str="";
var id = '#review';
$(id + ' th').each(function() {
  str += $(this).text() + "\t";
});
$(id + ' tr').each(function() {

  $(this).find('td').each(function() {
    str += $(this).text() + "\t";
  });

  str += "\n";

}); 
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(str));`

Comment: Doesn't compile the HTML tag inside, so if I have a <b>test</b>, it shows the tags.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, If you don't want html tags to appear in the output you can use `$(this).text()` instead of `$(this).html()`.  As far as I know if you open even an `.html` file using excel it won't render the tags so it may not be possible to open an excel file with html rendered output.

Comment: @rps Thanks. I figured as much. I took a different approach and have it working. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files